# Zapier error "You must return a single object or array of objects."

Tags: zapier

I'm trying to make a Zap that POST data to my API and after doing stuff on my side, my API returns a HTTP200 status code. Everything works on my side, but Zapier keep returning a "You must return a single object or array of objects" error. Is there something wrong with my code (Zapier side)?

Here it is :

```
if(inputData.Status === "Accepted"){
  var data = {
    TypeTemplate: 1,
    Date: inputData.Date,
    DocteurExterneID: inputData.DocteurExterneID,
    NomDuDocteur: inputData.NomDuDocteur, 
    NomDuClient: inputData.NomDuClient, 
    CourrielClient: inputData.CourrielClient,
    Prix: inputData.Prix
  };

  fetch('http://myapiurl/Zapier/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
  }).then(function (res) {
    return {result:true};
  }).catch(function(error) {
     callback(error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change the following line :

```
 return {result:true};
```

to

```
callback(null, res.text());
```